# Trimming column values while selecting with InfluxQL in Grafana Dashboard

Tags: grafana, influxdb, grafana-variable

I have a table like below. Col1 values has parenthesis like val1(12). But when I write a InfluxQL query I want to remove parenthesis and just get remaining. When the InfluxQL query runs in the output **Val1(12)** will be **Val1**

**mytable**:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val1(12) | 332 | 0 | 1 |
| val2(4234) | 222 | 0 | 1 |
| val3(221) | 111 | 0 | 1 |

If i write `select * from mytable` it wil give as below :

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val1(12) | 332 | 0 | 1 |
| val2(4234) | 222 | 0 | 1 |
| val3(221) | 111 | 0 | 1 |

But i want the paranthesis to be removed after i run the sql like below :

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | 332 | 0 | 1 |
| val2 | 222 | 0 | 1 |
| val3 | 111 | 0 | 1 |

I couldnt find a solution for this. Should i use `trim` or `wildcard` or `regex` to do this? InfluxDB shell version is 1.7.6.
We will run this influxql in grafana dashboard.

Comment: Please confirm you are actually using InfluxDB as opposed to any other SQL RDBMS. Are you running InfluxDB on-prem or their _Cloud_ version?

Comment: Apparently InfluxDB *does not use ISO SQL* - instead it has its own SQL-like language ( https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/ )  - so we cannot really answer your question until you give more details.

Comment: We can run SQL queries in influx> console in linux. We also use grafana to run our queries to create dashboards. InfluxDB is datasource for our Grafana Dashboard. Even when i type influx in linux shell i can enter influx> console and run sql selects. But i will run SQL query in Grafana.

Comment: InfluxDB shell version is 1.7.6. so we can run sql in influxdb console

Comment: I'm not disputing that InfluxDB's language is _a form_ of SQL (or rather: _is SQL-like_, but it _isn't_ ISO SQL, and the distinction can be important.

Comment: Can you search for the position of the open parenthesis and then use that index to extract from the left? Perhaps concatenate a dummy paren at the end if matches are optional so that it's easier to guarantee a match.

Comment: It is InfluxQL, not SQL. Also InfluxDB doesn't have columns, but fields and tags. I would recommend to read InfluxDB doc to know more. You will find there also that InfluxQL doesn't have any functions for string modification. You may try upgrade your InfluxDB and use Flux (another InfluxDB query language and it is absolutely not like a SQL, so you won't be confused it with SQL)

Comment: I see. My problem is i have thousands of field values written with () like value1(4324), value2(4234)...value1231(42342). These are written by another tool accidentally. I have to correct them to  value1, value2...value1231 by removing paranthesis. How can i do this in influxDB version 1.7.6

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to make use of SUBSTRING.

e.g.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Col1,0 CHARINDEX('(',Col1)), Col2, Col3
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Sorry, just saw it was influxDB - no idea on syntax on this one!! My answer may not work.

Comment: Thanks my friend. Let me try.